# how to set different app icons respected to the iOS version

Tags: iphone, ios, icons

I am developing an universal app and using the following [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html) for configuring the app icons

My doubt is, the names used for icons in info.plist are predefined ?
does it takes automatically respected icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the naming convention it seems that the proper icon will be selected for the right context. Have a look at the [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).